# Why does A15 pin for DDR3 is use?

Tags: ddr3

I need to design a PCB for Linux and use two DDR3.
To have 1GB ram, I'm using two 16bit DDR3 (256Mx16) that are used in fly-by topology.
I have look at some examples, some DDR3 have 16bits address, some 15bit.
16bit ones used all the time where using fly-by topology examples.
Can I use 15bit one DDR in fly-by-topology? If so, what about pin A15?

Comment: 256Mx16 is 512MB not 1GB. The number of address bits required is dependent on the number of Row bits (usually). The 8GB part I am looking at requires A[0..15] for Row and A[9..0] for Column in a 512Mx16 configuration.

Comment: Yes, Needs it 16bits address in fly-by topology?